# How do you put a html + CSS + JS playground into your app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-webview

I need to put a html + CSS + Js playground into an android studio app (using kotlin)

I have no idea how to do it and I haven't found anything about on the internet

Comment: You might wish to edit your question and explain in detail what an "html + CSS + Js playground" is.

Answer (score -1):

Here I am sharing some resources:-

https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Full%20Stack%20Web%20App%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/01_Introduction

https://www.raywenderlich.com/201669-web-app-with-kotlin-js-getting-started

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html